# Find the coefficients in quadrature formula on $[0,1]$ with the nodes at $1/4$, $1/2$, $3/4$

Tags: calculus, integration, numerical-methods

In my worksheet I was given a question about numerical integration that says:

> Find the formula for $\int_{0}^{1}f(x)dx=A_{0}f(\frac{1}{4})+A_1f(\frac{1}{2})+A_2f(\frac{3}{4})$

I suppose the goal of this question is to find $A_i$, but won't that depend on our $f$?

Comment: I think the idea behind this concept is using those certain function values to construct a polynomial that interpolates these, and the polynomial is easy to integrate. (This all can be packed into these factors, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_integration#Methods_for_one-dimensional_integrals ) The term for this (pretty oldfashioned) is 'quadrature formula'. The most famous is the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_quadrature

Comment: That numerical integration formula isn't going to hold for all functions $f$. Does it maybe say you want a certain degree of precision?

Comment: Nope @ Petaro. It just states find formula for ....

Comment: Is it really an '=' in the question, or is it (for instance) '$\approx$'?

Comment: Stating that you'd like to receive an answer is pure clutter. The fact that you posted a question already conveys this information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Formulas like yours give you just an approximation of $\int_a^b f(x) dx$ if $f$ is a arbitrary function, but there can be found such constants $A_i$ that formula yields not only an approximation, but the real value of the integral of polynomials with degree $$-1 +\text{number of constants } A_i$$
or less.

In your case, find such $A_1$, $A_2$ and $A_3$ that your formula will return the real value for arbitrary function $p(x) = ax^2 + bx + c$ where $a,b,c\in \mathbb{R}$.

How to compute $A_i$? Insert in your formula $p_1(x) = 1$, $p_2(x) = x$ and $p_3(x) = x^2$ or any other $3$ linearly independent polynomials and solve the corresponding $3\times 3$ system. You will get constants $A_i$ that work for those three polynomials. Since integral of sum of functions is sum of integrals of that functions (and analogically for function, multiplied by a constant), your formula works for all polynomials of degree two or less.

Comment: And how do I find such $A_i$? It does not state "use trapezoid rule" or something like that

Comment: @OriaGruber I have edited the answer.

Comment: Using the suggested method, I found $A_0=\frac{2}{3}$, $A_1=-\frac{1}{3}$, $A_2=\frac{2}{3}$ is this correct?

Comment: Two simple checks are 1)that the sum of the $A_i$ has to be $1$ if you are going to integrate $1$ correctly, 2) because the points are symmetric around the center of the interval, to integrate $-\frac 12+x$ correctly they have to be symmetric.  Your answer succeeds on these counts.